# How to read data stored from csv

Tags: c++, file, store

I'm trying to learn on how to read data from .csv file. The code shows that the data from csv file is read line by line. After the data is stored on variable 
`string arrival;`, the substring from `arrival` is taken but I'm stuck on on how to take the substring of the first column from each row. Is there an alternative way to read the data from csv?   This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7tUL.png).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<exception>
#include<sstream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arrival,burst[1000];
    char string[] ="Job";

    char *tokenptr;


    int x=0;

    tokenptr = strtok(string," ");


    ifstream jobfile("job.csv");

    if(jobfile.is_open())
    {
    cout << "Successfully open file"<<endl;

    while(jobfile!=NULL)
    {
        getline(jobfile,arrival,',');
        cout << arrival << endl;
        try
        {
            if(arrival.length() < 30)
            {
            std::string jobstr = arrival.substr (28,1); //To take substring from arrival
            stringstream job(jobstr);
            int jobArr; // To convert string into integer
            job >> jobArr;
            cout<<"Job Arrival = " << jobArr <<endl;
            }

            if(arrival.length() == 30)
            {
                std::string jobstr = arrival.substr (29,2);
                stringstream job(jobstr);
                int jobArr; 
                job >> jobArr;
                cout<<"Job Arrival = " << jobArr <<endl;
            }

            if(arrival.length() > 30)
            {
                std::string jobstr = arrival.substr (30,2);
                stringstream job(jobstr);
                int jobArr = 0; 
                job >> jobArr;
                cout<<"Job Arrival = " << jobArr <<endl;
            }
        }
        // To check exception
        catch (std::exception const &exc) 
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception caught " << exc.what() << "\n";
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cerr << "Unknown exception caught\n";
        }


        for(int i=0;i < 4;i++)
        {
            getline(jobfile,burst[i],',');
            cout<<burst[i]<<endl;
        }

        tokenptr=strtok(NULL," ");
        if(tokenptr==0)
        {
            x+=1;   
        }
    }

    cout<<"Number of Job ="<< x <<endl;
    }
    jobfile.close();

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c

Comment: You could find a plethora of examples on the internet by searching for "c++ read file csv".  Always search first.  Searching is often faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: Why are you using *both* C-style strings and `std::string`?  See `std::string::find` for tokenizing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've been researching and currently still searching for more information on this. Okay will look into that. Thanks!